# Ubuntu 16.04 login loop and compiz

Tags: nvidia, login, compiz, lightdm

After trying a bunch of stuff, I eventually tried

```
unity --reset-icons
```

I get a message like:

```
Warning: no DISPLAY variable set, setting it to :0
(process:2053): dconf-warning **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error 
spawning command line 'dbus-launch --
autolaunch=d98463f4c1aa983d9fd6d0df22f42686 --binary-syntax --close-stderr': 
Child process exited with code 1
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
Invalide MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keycompiz (core) - Fatal: Couldn't open display :0
compiz (core) - Info: Stopping plugin: (core)
compiz (core) - Info: Unloading plugin: (core)
```

and running

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz
```

returns

```
error: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
```

It sounds like something is wrong with compiz but reinstalling it does nothing.

I've tried looking through previous threads like [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

I tried that first answer and it doesn't seem to be an issue of permissions on .Xauthority or /tmp

I tried other possibilities like updating Nvidia drivers but to no real avail.

I've tried reinstalling and reconfiguring lightdm and I've tried using gnome and lubuntu, which also get stuck in login loops but LXDE allows me to get to the desktop, though thats not much of a solution since it still seems video/graphics features aren't working with it.

Comment: I've had this happen to 2 14.04.5 installations, both after Ubuntu automatic updates a week or so ago (I've worked around the absence of these 2 machines waiting to find a fix). Have tried a similar bunch of potential fixes, all to no avail.

Comment: Might be related to this question. Talks about unfreezing Ubuntu desktop which happens when compiz goes wrong. 
https://www.franzoni.eu/unfreezing-your-desktop-when-compiz-goes-wrong/